# VB.NET The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed

Tags: vb.net, web-services

The below code works on some URLs, but some other URLs having parameters return the error: `The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.`

my work:

```
        Dim objHttpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = Nothing
        Dim objHttpWebResponse As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
        Dim objRequestStream As Stream = Nothing
        Dim objResponseStream As Stream = Nothing
        Dim objXMLReader As XmlTextReader

        Try
        objHttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL)

        'Start HttpRequest
        objHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST"
        objHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml"

        'Get Stream Object
        objRequestStream = objHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
        objRequestStream.Close()

        'Start HTTP Response
        objHttpWebResponse = objHttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

        If objHttpWebResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
            objResponseStream = objHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
            objXMLReader = New XmlTextReader(objResponseStream)

            Dim xmldoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
            xmldoc.Load(objXMLReader)
            XMLResponse = xmldoc
            objXMLReader.Close()
        End If
```

Is the problem in the method I am using? or the content type?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the status code, the problem is in the method. Not all of the URLs might be able to respond to `POST` requests.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) states

> **405 Method Not Allowed**
>
> A request was made of a resource using a request method not supported
>   by that resource; for example, using GET on a form which requires data
>   to be presented via POST, or using PUT on a read-only resource.

Comment: Thank you @Markus, When I changed the method to "GET", it returned the exception: 
"Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type"
when calling the method GetRequestStream()

Comment: @Samer_Azar in a GET request, you do not include a body. You don't need to set a content type and also I'd avoid to access the request stream.